A problem with TColorGridSeries: stuck pattern
I'm using TColorGridSeries for my app and the problem I faced is rather weird: when I generate large amount of x-axis points (let's say >1000) with rather small displaying window (10-15) the series values kind of stuck starting from some X-axis scroll position. It starts roughly from about 1/3 of the whole X-axis range and I end up with the situation like on the screenshot below. When I move back to the left it normalizes by itself eventually.

Any advice'd be greatly appreciated.
I tried to play with a X-axis window but I can't do a lot with it and it gave no result.
